# Pandas - Python - How to change the contents of one column based on the content of two others?

Tags: python, string, datetime, pandas

I have two string columns and one datetime column:

I'm want to check if the first string column is a certain value
then to check if the datetime column is before a certain date
then to update the third string column to a new value.

I can create a variable to provide the date to match the datetime column against:

```
import time
june2014 = time.strptime('01-06-14','%d-%m-%y')
```

I'm looking for the syntax which can do this?

Comment: datetime objects can be compared easily:   'datetimeObject1 > datetimeObject2'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide real data but the following should work:

```
df.loc[(df['str1'] == some_string) & (df['time'] < june2014 ), 'str2'] = some_new_str_val
```

This uses `loc` to perform label indexing and then 2 conditions which use `&` as we are comparing arrays and with parentheses becuase of operator precedence.

Example:

```
In [4]:
# create some dummy data
import datetime as dt
df = pd.DataFrame({'str1':['hello', 'python', 'goodbye'], 'str2':['','',''], 'date':[dt.datetime(2013, 3, 4), dt.datetime.now(), dt.datetime(2014,7,14)]})
df

Out[4]:
                        date     str1 str2
0        2013-03-04 00:00:00    hello     
1 2015-02-20 20:19:34.224030   python     
2        2014-07-14 00:00:00  goodbye     

In [7]:
# create our date for comparison
june2014 = dt.datetime(2014, 6, 1)
df.loc[(df['str1'] == 'hello') & (df['date'] < june2014 ), 'str2'] = 'updated'
df

Out[7]:
                        date     str1     str2
0        2013-03-04 00:00:00    hello  updated
1 2015-02-20 20:19:34.224030   python         
2        2014-07-14 00:00:00  goodbye
```

Comment: hey thanks, this is great. I'm wondering though (because I get an error) where it says 'SettingWithCopyWarning' - I'm warned that 'A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.' Does this mean that the new value is set just to a copy of the Dataframe or to the actual Dataframe?

Comment: Yes that is correct, you need to index using `loc`, `iloc` or `ix` to ensure that the assignment is happening on a view, see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy